# How to extract text inside a <p> with a <small> tag

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

Currently I'm scraping a news site for a research work here I used python+BeautifulSoup  as follows

```
newsPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(newsPage.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding="iso 639-3")
newsText = newsPageSoup.find(class_='post-content').get_text()
```

to obtain the text part from the following html code. It worked fine.

```
<p class="post-content">The completion of the sixth review, upon the granting of a waiver of non‑observance for the end‑June 2019, performance criterion on the primary balance</p>
```

But the case is I want to extract the text part Andrew from following

```
<p class="text-primary" style="color : #2793ed; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">Andrew <small style="color:#999999; font-size:11px">Friday, 13 December 2019 07:58 PM </small> </p>
```

So I used the python code same as above

```
readerNames = newsPageSoup.find(class_='text-primary').get_text()
```

but it gives the following error

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

I think it is because of the `<small>` tag inside the `<p>` tag.So Is their a way to do that? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the text value as this:

```py
import bs4
l = '<p class="text-primary" style="color : #2793ed; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">Andrew <small style="color:#999999;font-size:11px">Friday, 13 December 2019 07:58 PM </small> </p>'
newsPageSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(l)
readerNames = newsPageSoup.find(class_='text-primary').text
```

Comment: @BenSV mark it as the currect answer and vote up if you think it is the right answer :)